# Can asterisk set-up a three-way call on an analog (classic) line?

Tags: asterisk

I would like to know if it is possible for *asterisk* to establish a [three-way call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conference_call) on an [analog line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_switched_telephone_network).

Typically, **I would like asterisk to call 2 numbers, with the same telephonic line, and connect them together**.

For a human, this is already possible on the line I'm using, by following those steps:

- pick up and dial the 1st number, wait for it to answer,
- press `R` (the [hook flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_flash)) and compose the 2nd number, wait for answer,
- press `R` and then `3` so everybody is now in the same conversation.

This is interesting here because the line I'm talking about can make international calls to many destinations without extra charge, so I can use it (as a relay) to call from one country (when travelling) to another without having to ruin myself.

Can asterisk reproduce these steps automatically, and do you know how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible with some [dialplan](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Dialplan+Fundamentals) scripting.

- You would want to use the [Dial()](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Dial+Application) application to "pick up and dial the 1st number".
- With a dumb analog line, you might not get any indication that the call was answered by the remote side. You can either have the first callee enter a DTMF digit when they pick up to indicate that it's time to call the next number or try to use call progress detection (callprogress=yes in chan_dahdi.conf).  Call progress on analog lines isn't an exact science since it uses DSP techniques to try and determine when the line is ringing, or someone answers, etc..
- You can use the [Flash()](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_Flash) dialplan application to send the hook flash.
- You can use the [SendDTMF()](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_SendDTMF) dialplan application to dial the 2nd number.  Same problem with knowing when the line is answered by the remote side.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any tweaking needed for the `Flash()` duration? I've heard it can be different between countries.

Comment: Yes. What you want is most likely txflash in  [chan_dahdi.conf](https://github.com/sruffell/asterisk-working/blob/svn_trunk/configs/chan_dahdi.conf.sample#L493-L505).

Comment: I see no mention of `txflash`, but there is `rxflash`, is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry. I meant just 'flash'.